# How to set sort order for crosstab in pentaho report designer?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have a pentaho report with crosstab, and i need to sort rows by 'sort_order' field, and this field should not be visible inside crosstab. So, is it possible? And if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it as follows:

1) Turn-off the auto-sort property for Master report (select "Master report" on the Structure tab, then set attributes -> query -> auto-sort to false)

2) Presort data in the query that you're using as a source for the crosstab: first sort by the field that defines rows order, then by the field that defines columns order (i.e. for rows order sort the query by the sort_order field).